# What domains are there other than unit ball and polydisc, on which Caratheodory metric is known?

Tags: reference-request, several-complex-variables

What are few (bounded)domains in $\mathbb{C}^n$ on which the explicit expression of Caratheodory metric is known. For example, unit ball and unit polydisc.

Comment: Do you mean the Carnot-Caratheodory metric on the boundary?

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz I am not familiar with the term Carnot-Caratheodory metrics.

Comment: I mean the metric $C_{\Omega}(z,w)=\sup\{p(f(z),f(w)): f:\Omega \to \mathbb{D}\},$ where $p$ denotes Poincare metric on unit disc $\mathbb{D}$, $f$ is holomorphic.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by 'known'. For instance, for convex domains one knows the equality of Kobayashi and Caratheodory metrics and that the external disks are convex, intersections of the domain with convex lines. This computes the metric modulo 'knowing' the explicit Riemann mappings from convex domains in the complex line.

Comment: @MoisheKohan For convex domains, are there few examples on which these Riemann mappings from domain in convex line can be computed (which as you explained in your comment, will compute the metric)?